# How to set an option value for an ESLint rule?

Tags: eslint

I'd like to change my ESLint rules to set the option `"properties"` value to `"never"` on the `"camelcase"` rule. I've read the docs two or three times but didn't quite understand how one does that. [Camelcase rule docs](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/camelcase)

This is my current `.eslintrc.json`:

```json
{
  "env": {
    "es2021": true,
    "node": true
  },
  "extends": ["airbnb-base", "plugin:import/typescript"],
  "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
  "parserOptions": {
    "ecmaVersion": 12,
    "sourceType": "module"
  },
  "plugins": ["@typescript-eslint"],
  "rules": {
    "camelcase": ["error"],
    "linebreak-style": "off",
    "comma-dangle": "off",
    "implicit-arrow-linebreak": "off",
    "import/extensions": [
      "error",
      "ignorePackages",
      {
        "ts": "never"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it this way.

```
"rules": {
    "camelcase": ["error", {"properties": "never"}],
    ....
}
```